# Tokyo Full Screen Layout starts from left and stops in the middle of screen

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout

In SharePoint 2013, why does the content inserted in a page with Tokyo full screen layout start from left of the screen and stop in the middle? How can I make the content go all the way to the right hand side of the screen?

[image]

Looking for a best practice solution. I've tried doing things like modifying `tokyo.css`, `tokyo-alternate.css` and even specifying my own custom css. I can change different styles except stretching the content across the page - which ideally I should not be required to do since `Tokyo` is a full screen page layout.

Comment: I know seattle and oslo but what is Tokyo?

Comment: It's there in the layout dropdown in 2013 when you "change the look"- out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:block` is what I needed.

```
.fullPageLayout{margin:0 auto; width:70%; display:block;}
```